# Counting expressions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I want to count the number of times that `^` occurs in an expression `x`, that's easy:

```
Count[x, _Power, {0, Infinity}]
```

Suppose I want to count only instances of -1 raised to some power.  How can I do that?

I had tried

```
Count[(-1)^n + 2^n, _Power[-1, _], {0, Infinity}]
```

and even

```
Count[Plus[Power[-1, n], Power[2, n]], _Power[-1, _], {0, Infinity}]
```

but both gave 0.

The origin of the question: I'm building a `ComplexityFunction` that allows certain expressions like `Power[-1, anyComplicatedExpressionHere]` and `Sqrt[5]` (relevant to my problem) but heavily penalizes other uses of `Power` and `Sqrt`.

Comment: The code should be `Count[x, _Power, {0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Just a small note that `Power` does not always correspond to a `^` somewhere in the expression, e.g. `1/x` is `Power[x,-1]` in `FullForm`.  Just be aware that there are a few quirks like this, in case it's relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do `Count[x,Power[-1,_], {0, Infinity}]`

```
In[4]:= RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 10]^RandomChoice[{x, y, z}, 10]

Out[4]= {(-1)^x, (-1)^x, 0^y, 0^z, (-1)^z, 1, 1, 1, (-1)^y, 0^x}

In[5]:= Count[%, (-1)^_, {0, Infinity}]

Out[5]= 4
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tried `Count[(-1)^n + 2^n, _Power[-1, _], {0, \[Infinity]}]` before I posted and it gave 0.

Comment: This is because `_Power` matches `Power[___]` and so your pattern was looking for `Power[___][-1,_]` and there is none. Your pattern would match `(a^b)[-1,n]`, which has full form `Power[a,b][-1,n]`. The correct pattern should be `Power[-1,_]`.

Answer (score 4):

What is about

```
Count[expr, Power[-1, _], {0, Infinity}]
```

P.S. Example in the question is not correct. I think you probably mean

```
Count[x, _Power, {0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably

```
Count[x, Power[-1, _], Infinity]
```

- the level specification of `Infinity` includes all levels 1 through infinity
- pattern `Power[-1, _]` will only match the the instances of `Power` when the radix is `-1`